# Export Blackberry IT Policy List to plaintext

Tags: blackberry, export, bes

Is there a possibility to export the Blackberry Enterprise Server 10 IT Policy to plaintext? At the moment I find only ways to export it in an encrypted way and I can't open it afterwards on any other device. I'd like to be able to audit the policy automatically by a script, once it's imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after is to export the policy rules, and not the actual policy itself (which would be encrypted and come with an xml file for future import).

See here:

[Export IT policy rules in BES](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do;jsessionid=EBF99E22806E7F28CDFBAAF9944D755A?externalId=KB17422&sliceId=2&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&noCount=true&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl)